# Measuring voltage but no power with DMM

Tags: multimeter, voltage-measurement, electronic-load

Hello guys i am a novice electronic engineer and i run up to a question on some troubleshooting i was doing.

I have an old audio door phone system that has 2 designed outputs for the 12VAC electric strike (door). When a resident presses the button from the indoor device those 2 outputs supply 12VAC to the electric strike.
As i was measuring voltage with DMM on those 2 outputs i was getting 11-12VAC but the electric strike was not working but as long as the resident was pressing the button i measured 12-13VAC and the electric strike was working as it should.
Some other systems i measured was 0-1VAC with no button pressed and when the button pressed it was 12-13VAC.
Can someone explain how is this possible and is there any other measurement to do so i won't be confused?

Answer (score 0):

Your DMM has very high input impedance (typically something like 10MΩ), so any leakage in the output switch will cause a reading with no load. It's not uncommon to have something like a snubber (resistor + capacitor) or MOV across a relay contact so that would cause the DMM to read a non-zero voltage. Even wiring that runs together has a bit of capacitance (as does the relay itself) and that will cause a non-zero reading.

To be sure the output is functioning properly, measure the voltage with a load, either the intended load or something roughly equivalent.